# Как установить соединение с сервером с базой данных php?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Я работаю в phpMyAdmin. И мне нужно подключиться в серверу.

Вот что мне нужно сделать:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот что я пытаюсь сделать:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я дела не так?

Comment: А что ты ожидаешь от написанного тобой кода?

Comment: Код нужно писать кодом, а не картинками. а PMA тут вообще не в тему.

Answer (score 1):

На Хабре есть отличная статья, [Как правильно использовать mysqli](https://habr.com/ru/articles/662523/). Её надо прочитать целиком, но для данного вопроса можно взять оттуда код соединения

```
$host     = '127.0.0.1';
$db       = 'test';
$user     = 'root';
$password = '';
$port     = 3306;
$charset  = 'utf8mb4';

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$db = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $db, $port);
$db->set_charset($charset);
$db->options(MYSQLI_OPT_INT_AND_FLOAT_NATIVE, 1);
```

Для того чтобы узнать, что именно вы делаете не так, надо еще сконфигурировать показ ошибок РНР. Для этого можно добавить следующие строчки

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1); // на боевом сервере поменять на 0
```

После этого в случае ошибки причина будет выведена в браузер. Останется только прочитать сообщение об ошибке и исправить её. Если сообщение непонятно, то его следует загуглить.

Comment: У меня не подсвечивается синтаксис языка. Это нормально?

Comment: Сама ошибка именно в синтаксисе

Comment: Где не подсвечивается? Какая ошибка? При чем здесь соединение с БД?

Comment: @Ипатьев походу просто в html-файл свой код засунул и чего-то ждёт

Comment: @Ипатьев Ну у меня на 2 скрине показано, как я написал в phpMyAdmin. И код не подсвечивается. Это нормально? Этот код я вишу на вкладке SQL

Comment: @7wafer7 этот код надо писать в файле .php

Comment: Я не совсем понял. А где мне его написать?

Comment: @7wafer7 сначала объясните, зачем вам вообще нужно это соединение. Обычно люди, которым нужно соединение с базой данных в РНР, уже имеют представление о том, что такое РНР и куда его писать. Так что либо вам не нужен РНР, и тогда вы должны объяснить, зачем вам это соединение, или надо сначала освоить основы РНР, выполнить скрипт hello world, и уже потом соединяться с БД

Comment: Ну так по заданию нужно. Но немного не понимаю, где мне нужно написать php код

Comment: Возьмите учебник, хотя бы Котерова, но лучше Дакетта. И начинайте учить - что такое пхп, как его запускать - и так далее. Постепенно дойдете до баз данных.